# About Datastore Write Operations daily limit？

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My app writes 5000 entities to datastore daily, and each entity includes 6 columns, but this datastore write operatons reach the free max limit（50000 times）？
Why occur this problem？

Comment: Have a look at appstats, to see what happens. Docs : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** As of July 1st, 2016, the unit of measure is now "Entity Writes" with a free tier of 20,000. This is independant of indexes so this would no longer exceed the free tier and only cost 5,000 Writes.

If all 6 columns of your entity are indexed you are doing at least `(2 + 6*2) * 5000 = 70,000` writes which exceeds the daily quota. From the billing page of Google App Engine:

> New Entity Put (per entity, regardless of entity size):
>   2 writes + 2 writes per indexed property value + 1 write per composite index value

Source: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing

Comment: How much write for non indexed property?

Comment: Un-indexed properties do not add extra write operations. So if you have a model with only un-indexed properties, writing the property will cost 2 writes.

Comment: Added an update at the top for anyone stumbling here since the calculation is now out of date

Comment: Thanks @DanMcGrath :)